# Early-intermediate Ralph Vaughan Williams Piano?

Tags: piano, repertoire

I'm (perhaps) an 'early intermediate' pianist. Are there any Vaughan Williams pieces I could look at that I have a reasonable chance of being able to play? Wikipedia suggests that I may be out of luck due to a complete absence of solo piano, but I'm not inclined to assume that it's 100% correct.

Comment: His first name is pronounced "Rafe," but is indeed spelled Ralph.

Comment: There is currently one close vote. Users voting to close are kindly invited to state their reason in comments as a courtesy to the original poster.

Comment: @oge normally I'd shrug, but as part of the beta process I agree with you. Advertising discussions of topicality and such is good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.rvwsociety.com/workskeyboard.html) is a list of his keyboard works.

There's one called "Six Teaching Pieces," and I found a [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHbdFC1_GVM&feature=related) of someone playing one of the movements from it. Does it sound like it's within your ability level?

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to have a look at some of his songs for voice and piano. In many of them, the piano accompaniment is not too difficult, and the piano doubles the voice, so it's "complete" as a "Song Without Words." (For example, his *Three Poems by Whitman* aren't too complex.)